# Apple TV and PC monitor - how to control the volume?

Tags: audio, appletv, airplay, youtube

I've got Apple TV 3, solely to AirPlay YouTube to my monitor with speakers connected to it.

I can't adequately express my feelings when I discovered I can't control the output volume while playing YouTube - it's always on max. Interestingly, playing from the Photos App, I can control the volume, but not from the YouTube App! The volume buttons do nothing.

I'm shocked, I'm ireful. How, how can it be made this way? Or do I miss something?

I even jailbroken TV, but it seems there's no way to install any tweaks, it seems useless.

How do I  make it work?

Comment: When you change the volume in Photos, is it changing the volume on the monitor itself or within the Photos App on Apple TV?

Comment: I'm not sure, I only see the volume bar on the phone. It seems nothing in the monitor settings changes (via DDC/CI as it can be done with a computer connected to monitor). 
Seemingly it works the same way as my Humax TV does - it's altering the overall volume level not messing with monitor settings.

Comment: Oh, I might misunderstand you. I meant Photos app on iPhone, Apple TV Photos app wasn't tested. I never used it :D

Comment: Ok.  Then what you’re dealing with is a limitation of the App.  The Photos App gives volume control *within* the App whike YouTube doesn’t.  You’re not controlling the actual volume out, just the vokume within the app itself.

Comment: Both the AppleTV and the TV need to support [CEC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consumer_Electronics_Control) You cannot change the volume of the signal over HDMI, so you need to either turn down the output [before it hits HDMI] or the TV's volume [after it arrives]. I know the Apple TV 4k supports it, but idk about the 3. A computer monitor is less likely to support CEC than an actual Television. https://support.apple.com/HT205225

Comment: Well... It seems my Benq GW2280 doesn't have anything like CEC. Only DDC which I extensively use with a computer.
That's not an omission by Apple, that's a screw up! And no workaround at all? 

Comment: Not that I know of, but I don't really know the Apple TV. My system runs a dedicated Mac to an actual TV & AVR. I can turn the Mac up/down with the keyboard, but I've a handful of TV/AVR remotes here too, all of which route over E-ARC to the AVR, which becomes the global volume control.